# Change keyboard layout with r_shift and r_alt in Lubuntu(LXQt)

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, lxde, input-language, lxqt

I want change my keyboard layout, like Windows with right Shift and right Alt. But now just can one time change. left Shift + left Alt is working but right Shift and right Alt work for one time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtmLy.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Can you upload a picture of your keyboard? May be the right Alt key you think it is, actually an Alt_Gr key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way but this way worked for me.

Edit your secondary keyboard layout symbols language file in path:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

Example: for Persian(Iran) language:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir
```

And **delete** all the following lines of code from the file:

```
include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

You can use Replace(Ctrl+H) option in your editor.

**reboot at the end.**

Comment: With that, and if you didn't do anything more, you don't have access to 3rd and 4th level symbols on your Persian layout.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Ubuntu and not on Lubuntu. With Ubuntu I would use *Tweaks* and enable the following settings:

**Switching to another layout**

- Check the "Alt + Shift" option (maybe you have already done the Lubuntu equivalent to that)

**Key to choose the 3rd level**

- Check the "Right Alt never chooses 3rd level" option
- Check the "Left Alt" option

The reason for the two latter is that the Persian keyboard layout you are using defaults to define <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as the key to access 3rd and 4th level symbols. That's why you could switch from English to Persian using <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> but not back to English.

But with the above options, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> is defined as the 3rd level key instead, and hence <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> always works for switching to next keyboard layout.

Hopefully you can find your way in the Lubuntu GUI to set those options.

*Edit:*

One way which may work on Lubuntu is to open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and set `XKBOPTIONS` there like this:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,lv3:ralt_alt,lv3:lalt_switch"
```

Then reboot and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I use LXQt Keyboard Layout and it does not have the options you mentioned. I also tried to install Tweaks, but it did not work. Do you not know the command or config file that I can enable these options?

Comment: @SajadMomeni: Well, I know the command line equivalent to using Tweaks. But if Tweaks doesn't work, the command line option would be slightly different.

Comment: @SajadMomeni: I edited my answer and added a variant which you may want to try.

Comment: I edit /etc/default/keyboard file but now change keyboard layout just with Right Left + Right Shift but i want change layout with both Shift + Alt (Right or Left). Now my hotkey not working for example Alt+Ctrl+T just work in Right Alt and Ctrl and this is problem.

Comment: I change XKOPTIONS to **grp:alt_shift_toggle,lv3:ralt_alt** and problem solved now i can change layout with both alt_shift But I can not change with rshift_ralt, I must first press ralt and then rshift to work. Can't I like the left to change anyway, not just when I first pressed ralt?

Comment: @SajadMomeni: I also noticed that latter behavior. Can't tell if/how it can be solved. But I'd also like to point out that you now have a new problem: You have no way to access 3rd and 4th level symbols when using your Persian layout. So you should really pick some key to choose the 3rd level.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I solved the problem in a different way. I do not know if it is principled or not, but the answer is for me. I will post my answer below. Thanks again